# How can I check the alignment of row_id and order variable in a task?

Tags: mlr3

I generated a task and assigned an order variable ("Date"). So, I have access to the following elements:

`task$row_ids` and `task$col_roles$order`.

The latter helps me to double-check the name of the ordering variable, so I can retrieve the order variable e.g. by `task$data(cols = c("Date"))`.

Now, as the row_ids are only guaranteed to be unique natural numbers (and not necessarily a sequence): How can I be sure that a command like

`Lookup<-tibble(task$data(cols = c("Date")), task$row_ids)`

generates a table that I can later use to recover the Date identifiers of the rows in `task$data()`? Or ist this trivial, as the order is respected by construction? (and I assigned order role to the Date column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have a lookup table with row ids with dates, you can get this with:

```
task$data(cols = c(task$backend$primary_key, "Date"))
```

Also note that `task$data(..., ordered = TRUE)` automatically reorders the data according to your `Date` column, but the default of the `ordered` argument is subject to change in the next release. If you are already working with ordered tasks (which is still kind of in development), explicitly state `ordered = TRUE` to be on the safe side.